# JPA Criteria API + PostgreSQL filter by date with minute precision

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpa, criteria-api

Due to a well known [Hibernate+Postgres bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-13155?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel) I decided to use Criteria API as many of my arguments can be `null` (fed from REST call).

As Criteria API behaves differently with each db client I can not get the solution when it comes to dates (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format). Anything that worked for me has not been satisfying as either I am loosing precision or I am getting exceptions. To the point:

Here is the field/column definition from my entity which maps to `timestamp` column type in Postgres Database:

```
@Column(name = "last_modified_date",
        nullable = false,
        updatable = false,
        columnDefinition = "TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE")
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
protected Date lastModifiedDate;
```

Here is the the JpaRepository interface where I use CriteriaAPI:

public interface PageHistoryRepository extends JpaRepository<PageHistoryEntity, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor {

```
default Page<PageHistoryEntity> findPages(Date fromDate,
                                          Date toDate,
                                          Pageable pageable) {
    return findAll(search(fromDate, toDate), pageable);
}

static Specification<PageHistoryEntity> search(Date fromDate, Date toDate) {
    return (root, cq, cb) -> {
        //To ensure we start with a predicate
        Predicate predicate = cb.isTrue(cb.literal(true));

        // this works but has no time precision
        if (fromDate != null) {
            Predicate _predicate = cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(root.get(PageHistoryEntity_.lastModifiedDate.getName()).as(java.util.Date.class), fromDate);
            predicate = cb.and(predicate,_predicate);
        }

        // this works aswell but again looses time precision
        if (toDate != null) {
            Predicate _predicate = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(root.get(PageHistoryEntity_.lastModifiedDate.getName()), toDate);
            predicate = cb.and(predicate,_predicate);
        }

        // this does not work
        if (toDate != null) {
            Predicate _predicate = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(
                    cb.function("date_trunc", Calendar.class, cb.literal("minute"), root.get(PageHistoryEntity_.lastModifiedDate.getName()).as(Calendar.class)),
                    cb.function("date_trunc", Calendar.class, cb.literal("minute"), cb.literal(toDate)).as(Calendar.class));
            predicate = cb.and(predicate,_predicate);
        }

        return predicate;
    };
}
```

}

The last of the predicates that I was hoping for it to work throws exception:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: function date_trunc(character varying, unknown) is not unique
  Wskazówka: Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

The format of the incoming date is fine, there is the value while debugging (it corresponds to the value sent from Postman so all is ok):

[image: debug]

[image: postman]

Here I also provide screen how the data looks in Postgres:

[image: postgres]

My question here is, how can I filter my search results by date knowing that the user might not provide any of dates or just one of them or both of them using Criteria API+PostgreSQL? Ideally I would like to my last Predicate that uses `date_trunc` to work but this is too ambitious for me now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess I experimented not enough, the proper way to build such criteria that would retain the time precision:

```
if (toDate != null) {
    Predicate _predicate = cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(
            cb.function("date_trunc", Date.class, cb.literal("minute"), root.get(PageHistoryEntity_.lastModifiedDate.getName())),
            toDate);
    predicate = cb.and(predicate,_predicate);
}
```